# Codename one Text Area not occupying full width

Tags: java, android, codenameone

Seems like this is a bug somewhere in the system, but for the sake of me being wrong, there is some settings i did not put in.

```
_reviewEnCustom.setFocusable(false);
_reviewEnCustom.getStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
_reviewEnCustom.getStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
_reviewEnCustom.setGrowByContent(true);
_reviewEnCustom.setShouldCalcPreferredSize(true);
_reviewEnCustom.setUIID("CafeDetailsDescription");
```

This is my text area, however the problem is it does not occupying the width, it stops short at 1/3rd of the page and breaks into a new line.
However when the editable is set to true, and try to edit, the width seems to be correct!!

also a track of the [issue 303 : Text Area faults](http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/detail?id=303#c3)

Lastly, the image .....[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNC3e.png).!

I have revised the code, by setting the column number, went from 15 to 500, no effect.

```
TextArea _reviewEnCustom = new TextArea(1,100);
            _reviewEnCustom.setText(reviewen);
            _reviewEnCustom.setEditable(false);
            _reviewEnCustom.setFocusable(false);
            _reviewEnCustom.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            _reviewEnCustom.getUnselectedStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);

            _reviewEnCustom.setGrowByContent(true);
            _reviewEnCustom.setUIID("CafeDetailsDescription");
            Container _reviewenContainer = new Container(_reviewenLayout);

            _reviewenContainer.addComponent(_constraint,_reviewEnCustom);
            _reviewenContainer.setUIID("CafeDetailsSubContainer");


            _detailsContainer.addComponent(lblTitle);
            _detailsContainer.addComponent(lblLocation);
            _detailsContainer.addComponent(_reviewenContainer);
```

Still no effect, using column width. I tried to check in the dicussion forum, no help. Got the latest source code down and built it, the textarea width doesnt consume the display width.

Only if i set it to editable, and click edit then the width is consumed. Else it breaks on the 1/3rd of the screen.

Any help? From what i m guessing is the way width is set in TextArea class itself. But i hope i am wrong.

> Came to a conslusion about 2 months ago, Was away travelling, That the
>   font will respond perfectly to the underlying library if the sizes are
>   in "Millimeters" and they should be embeded fonts not bitmap fonts.
>
> Never use bitmap fonts in Codenameone! There is a very easy way to
>   embed fonts!

Answer (score -1):

This is completely unrelated to the bugs you pointed at. You just need to define a large enough column count for the text area.

Your usage of `getStyle()` & `setShouldCalcPreferredSize()` is also incorrect. The latter shouldn't be invoked by user code and the former should be avoided, you should use explicit styles e.g. `getUnselectedStyle()`.